# WPF DependencyProperty Within a UserControl Bound to another UserControl not updating on coerce

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a parent usercontrol(NewSymbologyComboBox) with a contentpresenter that displays one of two controls.

The NewSymbologyComboBox control has a "SelectedOption" dependency property

```
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" >
        <!-- Presentations -->
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="EditablePresenter">
                <editableCombobox:EditableSymbologyComboBox SelectedOption="{Binding SelectedOption, ElementName=UserControl}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DropdownPresenter">
                <dropdownCombobox:DropdownSymbologyComboBox SelectedOption="{Binding SelectedOption, ElementName=UserControl}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <!-- Triggers -->
        <ContentPresenter.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable, ElementName=UserControl}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DropdownPresenter}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable, ElementName=UserControl}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditablePresenter}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentPresenter.Style>
    </ContentPresenter>
```

```
/// <summary>
        /// Property for the symbology setter to use on the plotted elements.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedOptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedOption", typeof(ISymbologyOption), typeof(NewSymbologyComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new UserDefinedSymbologyOption(""), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, PropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is ISymbologyOption option)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(option.DisplayName); //This is not called on the coerced initial change.
            }

            
        }
```

---

Both the EditableSymbologyComboBox and the DropdownSymbologyComboBox have a dependencyproperty SelectedOption in them as well.

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedOptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedOption", typeof(ISymbologyOption), typeof(DropdownSymbologyComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new UserDefinedSymbologyOption(""), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, PropertyChangedCallback, CoerceValueCallback));
```

The DropDownSymbologyComboBox has a coerce callback which modifies the value if it is not in the available options.

```
private static object CoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
        {
            if (d is DropdownSymbologyComboBox comboBox)
            {
                if (!comboBox._isInitialized)
                    comboBox.PopulateOptions();

                if (basevalue is UserDefinedSymbologyOption userDefinedSymbology)
                {
                    var matchingOption = comboBox.AvailableOptions.FirstOrDefault(option => string.Equals(userDefinedSymbology.DisplayName, option.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                    if (matchingOption != null)
                        return matchingOption;

                    return comboBox.AvailableOptions.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }

            return basevalue;
        }
```

On My window I am displaying the selection as shown

```
        <combobox:NewSymbologyComboBox Margin="10 5 0 0" SelectedOption="{Binding PlotOptions.SelectedSymbology}" IsEditable="False"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlotOptions.SelectedSymbology.DisplayName}"/>
```

My default value in my view model is set to "My First Selection" which is not available in the options and should be coerced to the first item in the list...  The coerce function finds this and sets it to the first available option...

The problem I am having is that my window is not updating with this change.  It is displaying "My First Selection" until I make a change in the combobox manually.

Any help would be great!  Thanks

Comment: If you expect a coerced value to propagate through binding, it is not the case sadly.

Comment: Wow, that sucks..